# Best approach to update the UI

Tags: android, user-interface, android-intent

What is the best approach to *update* the UI from intent service when the user is navigating to other screen or application?

Comment: Have a look at `WebView` and deliver your UI and content as a website. This does mean a network connection is required.

Answer (score 0):

In your service:

Use a LocalBroadCastManager. In your service's onCreate, set up the broadcaster:

In your Activity:

Create a listener on onCreate:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.setContentView(R.layout.copa);
        receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                // update Ui.
            }
        };

}
and register it in onStart:

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver((receiver), 
        new IntentFilter(COPAService.COPA_RESULT)
    );
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    super.onStop();
}
```

You can broadcast the info from ur service and update Ui Of the activity from the receiver registered in the activity